# Sending data between C and C#

Tags: c#, c, winsock

I've been messing with detouring functions with in applications. My challenge that I have set up for my self, was to detour the application that uses sendto and recvfrom functions. The plan was to inject a dll and copy the buffer being sent and received to my C# application(via the same sendto and recvfrom the target application uses) for further analysis.

The problem I am having is that the bytes being sent from the target application to my program do not match what ollydbg is telling me the buffer truly is.

Example: `A8 E4 F5 3A 1C` is the real buffer of my target application. 
         `21-73-46-AB-21` is what my application gets after a BitConverter of `33 115 70 171 33`.

I suspect the issue involved here is the way both languages typecast there socket buffers(from a `char*` to a `byte[]`), I'm unclear as to why this is. But if anyone has an idea, now is the time to share.

**DLL:**

```
int Transmitting(const char *data, int datalength, char *sendType)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int buffsize = datalength + strlen(sendType) + 1;
    char *buff = (char*)malloc(buffsize);

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(sendType); i++)
        //Send type; is nothing more then a token of identification. (e.g. "!r" for receiving bytes)
    {
        buff[i] = sendType[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0, j = strlen(sendType); i < datalength; i++, j++)
    {
        buff[j] = data[i];
    }

    ret = Real_sendto(udpcon.sock, buff, buffsize, 0, 
        (const struct sockaddr *)&udpcon.server, udpcon.addrLength);

    free(buff);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        errorMsg("Error with sending to transmitter");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

**C# app:**

```
void DecodeMsg(byte[] data, int bytesrecv)
{
    byte[] newdata = new byte[bytesrecv - 2];

    Array.Resize(ref data, bytesrecv);

    for (int i = 0, j = 2; j < bytesrecv; i++, j++)
    {
        newdata[i] = data[j];
    }

    switch (Convert.ToChar(data[1]))
    {
        case 's':
            forms.Invoke(forms.GUISendLog, new Object[] { newdata });
            break;
        case 'r':
            forms.Invoke(forms.GUIRecvLog, new Object[] { newdata });
            break;
    }
}

private void recvLogFunc(byte[] data)
{
    string msg = BitConverter.ToString(data);
    msg = msg.Replace("-", " ");

    recvlog.Items.Add(msg);

    recvlog.SelectedIndex = recvlog.Items.Count-1;
}
```

Comment: Showing some code would be very useful.

Comment: .NET strings are unicode in C use widechartomultibyte to get multibyte array equivalent to unicode string and for reverse use multibytetowidechar . char is ansi or multibyte but wchar_t for unicode. Or simply you can just replace char with wchar_t in C code.